# Decorator class decorating a class method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I've got a decorator that I've implemented as a class:

```
class Cached(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.cache = None
        self.func = func

     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if self.cache is None or (time.time() - self.cache[0] >= 1000):
             res = self.f(*args, **kwargs)
             self.cache = (time.time(), res)
         else:
             res = self.cache[1]
         return res
```

I want to use this decorator to decorate a method of a class, e.g.:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @cached
    def bar(self, y):
        return self.x + y
```

As it stands,

```
f = Foo(10)
f.bar(11)
```

throws `TypeError: foo() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`. `f.bar(f, 11)` works, but is the code smell equivalent of summer in New York City during a sanitation worker strike. What am I missing?

ETA: Originally, I was trying to implement Cached as a function:

```
def cached(cache):
    def w1(func):
        def w2(*args, **kwargs):
            # same 
        return w2
    return w1
```

but I kept getting weird scoping errors about `cache` being used before it's defined, which switching to a decorator class fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to your decorator class:

```
def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
     """support instance methods"""
     from functools import partial
     return partial(self.__call__, obj)
```